# Cypress command-line tool not honoring arguments

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm not using npm, so I've downloaded Cypress directly. I'm able to open the Cypress binary directly from the command line, but I can't make it run tests from the command line. Running `Cypress run` just opens the UI. `Cypress run --project /path/to/my/project` does open the project in the UI, but doesn't run it. Bizarrely, `Cypress version` doesn't display the version, it just opens the UI. Even `Cypress this-is-not-a-command` opens the UI without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `cypress` NPM package to run Cypress from the command line. The binary itself is not designed to be executed for anything other than global `open` mode. The `cypress` NPM package contains a command-line utility that makes `cypress run`, `cypress open`, and `cypress version` work like you expect.

---

If you really *really* **really** don't want to use the CLI supplied with the `cypress` NPM package, you can reference how the CLI translates your command line arguments:

- in `open` mode: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/cli/lib/exec/open.js
- in `run` mode: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/cli/lib/exec/run.js

Note that these APIs are internal and may change at any time.

So, to do `cypress run --project /path/to/project` directly on the binary, it would look like this:

```
cypress-binary --run-project /path/to/project
```